# Passing values to a function in Java

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am building an android app for work using android studio.  I  have a list of witnesses stored as sharedpreference, when the uses clicks to amend these witnesses are split up and listed the user can then click the witness they want to amend, well that's the plan, I just cant seem pass the witness listed number (basically the number used in the loop) to another function that will load the witnesses information into a form to be amended.  Below is my code:

```
            String s= WitnessDetails;
            String[] array = s.split("$_$(?=[0-9])");   

            LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout);
            // Layout inflater
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View view;

        for(String str : array)
        {
            countWitness++;
            String WitnessName= str;

            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.witnesses_activity, parentLayout, false);

            // In order to get the view we have to use the new view with text_layout in it
            TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.Witnesses_details);
            textView.setText("Witness 1: " + countWitness + "\n" + WitnessName+"\n Edit");

            // Add the text view to the parent layout
            parentLayout.addView(textView);

            textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View arg0) {                      
                    Amendwitness(countWitness);
                }
            });

          }

          public void Amendwitness(witnessNum){

          }
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that the error I am getting is because I have put the countWitness variable with the call to the AmendWitness, the error is AmendWitness() in witness_activity cannot be applied to (int)

Comment: Just for coding conventions: don't let variable or method names start with an uppercase letter! It's very confusing to other people, just as well as to the SO formatter ;)

Answer (score 2):

You are using `countWitness` inside an ***inner anonymous class***, so either

`countWitness` should be `final`

or

`countWitness` should be ***class field***

otherwise compiler will show error. Since `countWitness` is incremented inside for-loop, it cannot be declared `final`, so the only solution left is to make it as class-field

---

OR

you can use the `setTag(Object)` function

```
    for(String str : array)
    {
        countWitness++;
        String WitnessName= str;

        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.witnesses_activity, parentLayout, false);

        TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.Witnesses_details);
        textView.setText("Witness 1: " + countWitness + "\n" + WitnessName+"\n Edit");
        textView.setTag(countWitness); // set the countWitness as tag object

        parentLayout.addView(textView);

        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {                      
                Amendwitness((Integer)arg0.getTag());
            }
        });

      }
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. however I still get the error AmendWitness() in witness_activity cannot be applied to (java.lang.integer)  . the Editor has highlighted this extract as causing the error ((Integer)arg0.getTag());

Comment: whats the signature of AmendWitness() ?

Comment: its currently an empty function but will  be used to repopulate the the form with the witness information for amending.

Comment: signature means.. what is its parameter type? return type? can u put the function by editing your question?

Comment: Thanks sanbhat, my code has been edited to include the function as before its currently empty as I hadn't got that with this function to this current issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possibilities:

1. Add a custom `MyClickListener` class:

   ```
   public class MyClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
       private int mIndex;

       public MyClickListener(int index) {
           mIndex = index;
       }

       @Override 
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Amendwitness(index);
       }
   }
   ```

   Add your `OnClickListeners` like this:

   ```
   textView.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener(countWitness));
   ```
2. Use the tag of the View:

   ```
   textView.setTag(countWitness);
   textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View arg0) {                      
           Amendwitness(v.getTag());
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: An anonymous View.OnClickListener cannot have a constructor and thus cannot store the index value.